# Efficient SELECT for array of tuples in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

Assume I have a table `records` with the following structure

- id (unique int)
- updated (timestamp)

I have an `input_array` with values `[[id_1, timestamp_1], [id_4, timestamp_4], ...]`. I'll refer to each element as `tuple_1`, `tuple_4`, etc.

I'm looking for the most efficient query (in PostgreSQL v11.2+) to select `[id_1, id_4, ...]` from `records`, but only where `tuple_{n}.updated > row{n}.updated`. Assume `input_array` may contains thousands of tuples, and `records` upwards of a million rows.

I don't even know where to begin with this. `Lateral join` comes to mind, as does `unnest`, and `where in`, but everything I've tried so far fails miserably

**Update** I'm open to `input_array` being in any format (tuples, two separate arrays, whatever), and `updated` being an `int`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you aren't fixed on the array input, you can use a tuple comparison.

```
select *
from records
where (id, updated) in ( (1, timestamp '2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
                         (2, timestamp '2019-01-02 00:00:00') )
```

That can make use of a regular btree index on `(id, updated)`

Note that this uses `=` for **both** values and is equivalent to

```
where (id = 1 and updated = timestamp '2019-01-01 00:00:00')
   or (id = 2 and updated = timestamp '2019-01-02 00:00:00')
```

But you want to compare the timestamps using `>`. You can do that if you join against a `values` clause:

```
select r.*
from records r
  join (
    values 
       (1, timestamp '2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
       (2, timestamp '2019-01-02 00:00:00') 
  ) as t(id,upd) on  r.id = t.id
where r.updated > t.upd;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/GGC83046